# Dynamically Set Object name in for loop

Tags: excel, vba, object

I have a `for loop` with some conditions, I want to Create new `Objects` inside the for loop `dynamically` when met the `conditions`, i have commented the error in the code, Is there a way to accomplish this ? I am new to vba so xcuse my ignorant. Would appreciate any help.

```
Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("M16:M30")
x = 1
For Each rcell In rng1.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(rcell) Then
        If rcell = "1" Then
            Set family_member_&x = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")       // ERROR HERE
            family_member_&x.Add "family_group", "FG_1"
            family_member_&x.Add "name", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B"&x)
            family_member_&x.Add "date_of_birth", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("C"&x)
        ElseIf rcell = "2" Then
            Set family_member_&x = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            family_member_&x.Add "family_group", "FG_2"
            family_member_&x.Add "name", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B"&x)
            family_member_&x.Add "relationship", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("E"&x)        
        End If
        x = x +1
    End If
        

Next rcell
```

Comment: Usually when you think dynamic variables, think a `Scripting.Dictionary`. So you could create a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: how do you suggest it should be done with your approach, sorry but im not used to vba syntax and i want to call my api with those dictionaries :)

Comment: Create a `Scripting.Dictionary` outside your loop, then add new dictionaries to it within the loop using `"family_member_" & x` as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are wanting a Collection of family_member dictionaries. You can accomplish this by creating either a Collection or a Dictionary outside the loop and then adding each family member to that collection during the loop.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim Family As Object, familyMember As Object
    Set Family = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator")
    
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("M16:M30")
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In rng1.Cells
        If rCell = "1" Then
            Set familyMember = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            familyMember.Add "family_group", "FG_1"
            familyMember.Add "name", ws.Range("B" & rCell.Row)
            familyMember.Add "date_of_birth", ws.Range("C" & rCell.Row)
            Family.Add familyMember("name"), familyMember
        ElseIf rCell = "2" Then
            Set familyMember = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            familyMember.Add "family_group", "FG_2"
            familyMember.Add "name", ws.Range("B" & rCell.Row)
            familyMember.Add "relationship", ws.Range("E" & rCell.Row)
            Family.Add familyMember("name"), familyMember
        End If
    Next rCell
    
End Sub
```

At the end of the loop, you now have a Dictionary named `Family` that has one item for each `familyMember`. The items are accessible by their name like `Family("George")` and the item's items are accessible like `Family("George")("relationship")`. You can also loop through the collection directly like `For Each Member In Family.Items`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is it possible to remove the `("name")` part from the beginning of the dictionary? like i want to access the dictionaries of family_members by their `index` not a name. Thanks for your help. that really works well

Comment: You can access them by index using `Family.Items()(index)`, no changes needed.